# Remove specific characters in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bunch of files that look like this:

```
file1.csv
['Dog']
['Cat']
['Snake']

file2.csv
['Dog']
['Cat']
['Snake']
['Cat']
['Snake']
['House']
```

I want to remove the `['` and `']` characters from these files in a loop. How can I achieve this?

The result would look like this:

```
file1.csv
Dog
Cat
Snake
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tr`:

```bash
tr -d "[']" < file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '\w+' file
Dog
Cat
Snake
Cat
Snake
House
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` you can strip starting `['` and ending `']` in one `s` command:

```bash
sed -i.bak -E "s/^\['|']$//g" file

cat file

Dog
Cat
Snake
```